# Ошибка в доступе к изменениям в mysql на localhost!

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите по бд. Создал стандартную базу на локалхосте, добавил пользователя с логином и пассом root root. Спустя некоторое время почему-то мне отказывает в выполнении многих действий: добавление данных в базу, удаление триггеров и прочее.
В чём дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что выводит `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`?

Comment: Вот это - https://prnt.sc/gw3k2b

Comment: А должно быть так `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'localhost ....`. Вашему руту, действительно, не хватает некоторых прав. Возможно, Вы обновили MySQL сервер. Если это так, то выполните `mysql_upgrade.exe`

Comment: Что-то не помогло. Может быть есть смысл удалить MySQL Server и скачать снова?

Comment: Если не жалко, то удалите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не было нужных прав на пользователе.
Вопрос решен.